# How can I substitute characters in C#

Tags: c#

I have strings like this:

```
var abc = "text1 text2 text3";
```

I want to change "text3" to "textabc" in the string. Is there a way that I can do this without creating a new string?

Comment: Why do you want to do that ??

Comment: @Akram - I don't think it's a particularly obscure requirement? Why do you think it so?

Comment: @El Ronnoco: I want to know what does the OP really need ..

Comment: Take a look at [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3591089/string-immutability-in-c)

Comment: What do you mean by "creating a new string", and why do yuu think that you need to avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, because strings are immutable, but you can reassign the new string to the same variable

```
var abc = "text1 text2 text3"
abc = abc.Replace("text3", "textabc");
```

Comment: I believe this still allocates memory for both strings (ie `abc` pre-op and `abc` post-op) as per the example in Skeety's article from my answer

Answer (score 3):

Strings are immutable in C# so any operation inherently creates a new string...

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe.aspx)

> Strings are immutable--the contents of
>   a string object cannot be changed
>   after the object is created, although
>   the syntax makes it appear as if you
>   can do this.

[StringBuilders](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y9sxk6fy.aspx) are often the most efficient way to perform manipulation on a "string" due to this fact. Especially if you are concatenating one char at a time for example.

See the [StringBuilder.Replace()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3h5afh4w.aspx) method - This does not require you reassign the result to another StringBuilder as it *actually changes the StringBuilder itself*.

Have a look at [this article](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/stringbuilder.html) by the very famous [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) (you'll get to recongise him:)) all about using StringBuilder sensibly.

Comment: @Homam Thanks :) I think the OP was just asking how to reassign the result back to the original variable name though... d'Oh

Comment: Yes, that's it, from the level of the question I knew what the OP wants. Thanks for the article's link and its writer :P.

Answer (score 1):

```
string newString = abc.Replace("text3", "textabc");
```

Strings are immutables in the CLR : you can never ever change them.

Answer (score 1):

The main question is what do you mean by writing "without creating a new string".

As stated, strings are immutable in .NET, that is, once they're created, they can't change.

However, you can replace them with a new string instance:

```
var abc = "text1 text2 text3";  
abc = abc.Replace("text3", "textabc");
```

If you want more flexibility, you may want to use `StringBuilder`, in which you can remove and replace strings as much as you want, and finally use its `ToString` method to have the result as a string instance.