# Clearing a System.String in C#

Tags: c#

Will this overwrite the contents of my string:

```
unsafe
{
    fixed (char* chars = str)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
            chars[i] = '1';
    }
}
```

The background is I'm using [NetworkCredientials](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkcredential%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), in which you set the password using a plain old `System.String`. I'd like to "clear it" afterwards, if that's possible. Any suggestions on how to do this are welcome, but the main question is to understand if `fixed` will really give me access to the underlying char array. Thanks!

**Edit**

I would like to understand what *is* going on here - if a string object is immutable, and `fixed` doesn't let the object move then what's happening in the code posted? Where are those characters being written to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to understand what is going on here - if a string object is immutable, and fixed doesn't let the object move then what's happening in the code posted? Where are those characters being written to?

Strings are only immutable if you play by the rules. Here you are actually mutating the string by using unsafe code. (It's even possible with code that is "safe" in the sense that it passes `peverify` but that bends the rules in other ways, e.g. by calling the non-public `AppendInPlace` method via reflection or by [abusing union structs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/792735/why-does-this-code-work-without-the-unsafe-keyword).)

Breaking the rules like that is dangerous. It could interfer with [string interning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). It could corrupt memory locations which the .NET runtime relies on, like the TypeHandle and syncblk bytes that exist at the start of each .NET object. Etc.

Answer (score 13):

Use the [`NetworkCredentials` constructor overload taking `SecureString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783746%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. The whole reason for that overload is to avoid this problem. You shouldn't go trying to mutate `System.String` instances. (It's certainly possible with reflection, but should be avoided.)

Comment: Hmm. I've been restricted to .NET 3.5 unfortunately - that was the first thing I looked at.

Comment: @noelicus: In that case it would have been nice if you'd said so in the question. When there's a clear good answer which isn't applicable in your situation, you should always explain that you already know about that and that it *isn't* applicable in your situation.

Comment: Actually I meant I immediately looked for overloads in the NetworkCredentials constructor within Visual Studio and it wasn't there, rather than I knew all about it! If I knew I would have stated it, don't worry!

Answer (score 6):

`System.String` is immutable, so you can't modify it.

[From MSDN:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/362314fe.aspx)

> Strings are immutable--the contents of a string object cannot be
>   changed after the object is created, although the syntax makes it
>   appear as if you can do this.

If you need to erase the string for security reason, try looking at [SecureString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Security.SecureString%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

In fact, your code mutate the string, you can see an answer From Eric Lippert here: [String immutability in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3591175/128662):

> You can create a type where the CLR enforces immutability on it. You
>   can then use "unsafe" to turn off the CLR enforcement mechanisms.
>   That's why "unsafe" is called "unsafe" - because it turns off the
>   safety system. In unsafe code every single byte of memory in the
>   process can be writable if you try hard enough, including both the
>   immutable bytes and the code in the CLR which enforces immutability.

If you are really restricted to a version of C# without `SecureString`, then you have to use unsafe code. But maybe the best solution is to try harder to change version.

Comment: OK. So what's going on in the code I've posted? ... it can't create a new string for each character modification can it? ... because it's `fixed`

Comment: @noelicus: What's going on is *you are writing memory that you are not supposed to write to*, and therefore your program's behavior is undefined. Such a program can have any behavior at all; that you are observing a *particular* behavior does not contradict that fact, it confirms it.