# Should .NET strings really be considered immutable?

Tags: c#, .net, string, immutability

Consider the following code:

```
unsafe
{
    string foo = string.Copy("This can't change");

    fixed (char* ptr = foo)
    {
        char* pFoo = ptr;
        pFoo[8] = pFoo[9] = ' ';
    }

    Console.WriteLine(foo); // "This can   change"
}
```

This creates a pointer to the first character of `foo`, reassigns it to become mutable, and changes the chars 8 and 9 positions up to `' '`.

Notice I never actually reassigned `foo`; instead, I changed its value by modifying its state, or *mutating* the string. Therefore, .NET strings are mutable.

This works so well, in fact, that the following code:

```
unsafe
{
    string bar = "Watch this";

    fixed (char* p = bar)
    {
        char* pBar = p;
        pBar[0] = 'C';
    }

    string baz = "Watch this";
    Console.WriteLine(baz); // Unrelated, right?
}
```

will print `"Catch this"` due to string literal interning.

This has plenty of applicable uses, for example this:

```
string GetForInputData(byte[] inputData)
{
    // allocate a mutable buffer...
    char[] buffer = new char[inputData.Length];

    // fill the buffer with input data

    // ...and a string to return
    return new string(buffer);
}
```

gets replaced by:

```
string GetForInputData(byte[] inputData)
{
    // allocate a string to return
    string result = new string('\0', inputData.Length);

    fixed (char* ptr = result)
    {
        // fill the result with input data
    }

    return result; // return it
}
```

This could save potentially huge memory allocation / performance costs if you work in a speed-critical field (e.g. encodings).

I guess you could say that this doesn't count because it "uses a hack" to make pointers mutable, but then again it was the C# language designers who supported assigning a string to a pointer in the first place. (In fact, this is done [all](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/String.cs#L418) [the](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/String.cs#L364) [time](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Text/StringBuilder.cs#L651-L652) internally in `String` and `StringBuilder`, so technically you could make your own StringBuilder with this.)

So, should .NET strings really be considered immutable?

Comment: They are immutable when using public API. If your using unsafe code or reflection to bypass that public API they are not.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Pointers *are* part of the public API, also see my last paragraph.

Comment: I'm talking about public API of `string` class - the methods, properties it exposes.

Comment: thats not part of the public api - thats just how it was implemented.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek, @Daniel. A. White: Then why didn't Microsoft make `fixed` return, for example, a `ReadOnlyPtr<char>` for strings, that couldn't be coerced into becoming mutable?

Comment: To those downvoting - please hover over the up/down buttons and make sure you are downvoting for the right reasons.  Don't downvote just because you don't agree, or wouldn't recommend this approach.

Comment: @MattJohnson I'm guessing that people are downvoting because the question is somewhat dependent upon personal opinion (until someone of authority weighs in).  It's an interesting question, but a difficult one for SO to properly support.  However, rather than downvoting they probably should vote to close.  I'm not saying that that is necessarily correct mind you :).

Comment: It does show research effort, it is clearly worded, and it has useful knowledge.  That's all that matters.

Comment: It's safe to consider them immutable, but you're using `unsafe` code.

Comment: @ArturoTorresSánchez True, but again why does the compiler even *let* you have a pointer to a string in the first place? For most other objects (excluding value types) that's not possible.

Comment: Define immutability and we'll tell you if it can be considered it or not. Most people accept that `unsafe` code is "special" and is disregarded when talking about immutability in C#.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Immutability is being unable to change the state of the object using the public API. The fact that you can assign a string to a `char*` is part of the public API. Therefore, strings are not immutable.

Comment: Yeah, but I think the `unsafe` keyword is clear enough. What you're doing is not safe. Previous assumptions may not apply.

Comment: @JamesKo: on the other hand, unsafe code is just a door provided by C# to enter the C-world. Are you really still talking about C#/.NET's public API then? It's a vague notion and as I said, some (most?) devs just exclude it when talking about C# immutability.

Comment: @MattJohnson: it shows almost *zero* research effort - the accepted answer was literally straight from the language spec (I went back and added the word "almost", because I suppose opening the compiler and messing around with 'unsafe' and 'fixed' for a while - without ever Googling either one - might be considered research somehow)

Comment: P.S. Eric Lippert answered the *hell* out of this question five years ago: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3591175/4437569

Comment: @JohnCastleman Thanks for the link! My apology, I only asked this question because I wasn't aware that people knew about this already. Searching for ".net string immutability" basically gets you nowhere because you just get all of these questions asking what immutability is / why the .NET string is "immutable," so I just wanted to increase awareness.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

§ 18.6 of the C# language specification (*The `fixed` statement*) specifically addresses the case of modifying a string through a fixed pointer, and indicates that doing so can result in undefined behavior:

> Modifying objects of managed type through fixed pointers can results in undefined behavior. For example, because strings are immutable, it is the programmer’s responsibility to ensure that the characters referenced by a pointer to a fixed string are not modified.

Comment: Interesting, I've only ever heard the term "undefined behavior" used in the C/C++ specs (all the time). Seeing it in C# is something new.

Comment: @JamesKo There's even an instance of undefined behaviour in the C# spec that doesn't relate to `unsafe` code (the only one I could find in a quick search): if you use custom awaiters with `async`/`await`, and your custom awaiter invokes the continuation multiple times, the behaviour is undefined.

Comment: *This* is why to downvote this question ... the answer's explicitly covered in the language spec, and was apparently considered by the authors to be so likely a point of concern, they thought of it well ahead of time

Comment: @JohnCastleman My apology; I was just trying to increase awareness that strings aren't *really* "immutable" in .NET, to show that they're really no different from a `char[]` buffer under the covers.

Answer (score 1):

I just had to play with this and experiment to confirm whether the addresses of *string literal* are pointing into the same memory location.

The results are:

```
string foo = "Fix value?"; //New address: 0x02b215f8
string foo2 = "Fix value?"; //Points to same address: 0x02b215f8
string fooCopy = string.Copy(foo); //New address: 0x021b2888

fixed (char* p = foo)
{
    p[9] = '!';
}

Console.WriteLine(foo);
Console.WriteLine(foo2);
Console.WriteLine(fooCopy);

//Reference is equal, which means refering to same memory address
Console.WriteLine(string.ReferenceEquals(foo, foo2)); //true

//Reference is not equal, which creates another string in new memory address
Console.WriteLine(string.ReferenceEquals(foo, fooCopy)); //false
```

We see that `foo` initializes a string literal which points to `0x02b215f8` memory address in my PC. Assigning the same string literal to `foo2` references the same memory address. And creating a copy of that same string literal makes a new one. Further testing via `string.ReferenceEquals()` reveals that they are indeed equal for `foo` and `foo2` while different reference for `foo` and `fooCopy`.

It is interesting to see how *string literals* can be manipulated in memory and affects other variables that are just referencing it. One of the things that we should be careful of as this behavior exists.